# Converting date to Monday date of each week

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a `df`:

```
date
2021-06-28
2021-06-29
2021-06-30
2021-07-02
2021-07-04
2021-07-07
2021-08-06
2021-08-07
```

I am trying to convert this to week, I know I can use `df.date.dt.isocalendar().week` but this returns the week number with the default start date, whereas my start date is `2021-06-28`.
I can achieve the dates in `df` using `pd.Grouper(key = 'date', freq = 'W-MON', label = 'left', closed = 'left')` in a `groupby` but I would like to have the same output without using `groupby` - simply applying a function to `date` column.

My goal is to have:

```
date
2021-06-28
2021-06-28
2021-06-28
2021-06-28
2021-06-28
2021-07-05
2021-08-02
2021-08-02
```

Because these dates represent the Monday of each week that the date falls in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to 'W-SUN' [period](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and get the first day:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['Monday'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('W-SUN').dt.start_time
```

*NB. why 'W-SUN'? This indicates the weeks **ending** in SUN(day), so starting on Mondays. See [anchored offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases).*

output:

```
        date     Monday
0 2021-06-28 2021-06-28
1 2021-06-29 2021-06-28
2 2021-06-30 2021-06-28
3 2021-07-02 2021-06-28
4 2021-07-04 2021-06-28
5 2021-07-07 2021-07-05
6 2021-08-06 2021-08-02
7 2021-08-07 2021-08-02
```